# Issue with Given Solution for Problem - SOA FM Exam Practice

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I've been preparing for the FM exam coming up next month and am having some trouble understanding the solution given to Problem 24.15 in the book "A Basic Course in the Theory of Interest and
Derivatives Markets." The question is as follows:

You want to accumulate \$1,000,000. You intend to do this by making deposits of \$5,000 into an investment account at the end of each month, until your account balance equals \$1,000,000. The account earns 8% convertible quarterly. Determine the number of monthly deposits you will need to make to achieve your goal.

The book gives a solution of 127, while I found 128 as my answer. I worked the problem as follows:

$\$1,000,000 = 12 * \$5,000 * \frac{1.02^{t/3} - 1}{i^{(12)}}$

$i^{(12)} = [1.03^{1/3} - 1] * 12 = 0.0794725$

At the end of it all, we are left with:

$1.02^{t/3} = 2.32454$

$t = 3*ln(2.32454)/ln(1.02) = 127.7895$

Since the number of monthly payments would have to be an integer, I am under the impression that it should be 128. I would understand the solution being 127 if the sequence of 127 payments would accumulate to be \$1,000,000 by the time t = 128, but that is not the case; the accumulated value of the annuity for t = 127 is approximately \$990,877.25, and accumulating a month of interest to this amount leaves us with only \$997,439.54 in the account (short of our million dollar goal).

If there's something I missed here I would greatly appreciate the assistance - want to make sure I don't miss it again on the exam. Thanks!

Comment: Chris, you've used a formula for figuring this out which I don't comprehend. The $i^{(12)}$ in particular. My solution below is via a differential equation of a quarterly increase in P based on payments and 2% per quarter continuous growth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{dP}{dt} = .02P + 15000$

$\frac{50\cdot dP}{P + 750000} = dt$

$50\cdot \ln|P + 750000| = t + C$

$\ln|P + 750000| = .02(t + C)$

$P + 750000 = e^{.02C}\cdot e^{.02t}$

When $t = 0, P = 0$

$e^{.02C} = 750000$

$P = 750000e^{.02t} - 750000$  .....is the specific solution

When $P = 1000 000, t= ?$

$1000 000 = 750000e^{.02t} - 750000$

$.02t = \ln (\frac{1750000}{750000}) = \ln (2.3333333)$

$t = 42.36489$ quarters

$ = 42.36489\cdot 3 = 127.09$ months

Comment: Thanks Phil! My vote doesn't count yet but just know I gave you one! For reference though, the formula I used is on pages 239 and 240 of this book: https://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/actuarieshall/mainf.pdf. Any idea why that might not be a correct appllication?

Comment: It appears to underestimate the true percentage rate hence the need to add another payment. I tried to rationally figure what it was doing but couldn't. My solution is standard math for this kind of problem whereas your's is likely something used by financial institutions. Just to check, your formula is basically $P = A\cdot \frac{(1+r)^{t/3}-1}{i^{(12)}}$ where P is the accumulated amount, A the annual amount paid in, r the monthly interest rate, t the time period in months and i the monthly interest rate equivalent to r. I'll check this out again to see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: Edit, make r the quarterly interest rate.

Comment: I did some research into financial math and your formula is based on compound interest where the interest is computed at regular intervals and not continuous. Hence your formula has less growth. I suggest you use your formula for your exam and assume the answer in the book is just an anomaly.

Comment: That's all correct as far as what I used for my solution. Thanks for your help Phil. It's been bugging me since I saw it yesterday and a second set of eyes was helpful for sure!